# I need an SQL script which would search between time intervals

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I need an SQL query that will do the following:

```
select ..........
from ....
where ....
and arrival_time between systemtime and (systemtime + 7 hours )
```

Comment: Btw: the syntax for this is easily found in the manual

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use tochar function and intervel function to achieve this...
like

SELECT .....
FROM
WHERE ...
and to_char(arrival time,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') BETWEEN to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND to_char(sysdate + interval '7' HOUR,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss').

Comment: Don't use a transformation function on a column.  It 

a) executes for each row
b) prevents using any indexes that may be on the column

Comment: -1 Transforming a DATE or TIMESTAMP to a VARCHAR2 for comparison is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm not even sure if the BETWEEN operator correctly works with DATES converted to a character representation. And in this case it's definitely not needet to use to_char() as everything is a date already

Comment: This works and to_char() will make sure the date formats are similar.

Comment: @Capslockk: the date 'formats' are only meaningful when displaying the value to the user. When comparing them in the `where` clause they should be left as native Oracle date types, as in @a_horse_with_no_name's answer. You're not gaining anything, and may lose significantly, by converting to strings.

Comment: @Capslockk: but it remains a bad solution. Using to_char() breaks the usage of any index (which will slow down execution), is absolutely unnecessary and makes the whole statement hard to read.

Answer (score 5):

```
arrival_time BETWEEN current_timestamp AND current_timestamp + INTERVAL '7' hour
```